# Convergence of $\sum\frac{(n-a)^2}{(n-b)^3}$ with $a,b$ complex numbers.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, complex-numbers

Find the complex constant $a, b$ for which $\sum\frac{(n-a)^2}{(n-b)^3}$ converges and diverges.

Answer (score 1):

One may observe that, as $n \to \infty$,
$$
\frac{(n-a)^2}{(n-b)^3}=\frac1n\times\frac{(1-a/n)^2}{(1-b/n)^3}\sim \frac1n
$$ thus the considered series is **always divergent** as is the harmonic series.

Comment: exactly what significance $\sim$?

Comment: We say that the functions $f$ and $g$ are asymptotically equivalent (or $f \sim g$ for short) if the limit $\lim_{+\infty} \frac{f}{g}$ exists and is equal to $1$. In your case $f,g : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @user329587 We write, as $n \to \infty$, $u_n \sim v_n$ with the meaning that $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{u_n}{v_n}=1$.